# Node.js and Python together, in Heroku

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, sockets

I'm making a login page in HTML, with Node.js and Python. I'm trying to send the username and password from my client side JavaScript to Python, which is server side. The Python script will eventually do a bunch of other things, but right now I'm focusing on organizing database entries. I am already using io and socket in JavaScript, so I figured the easiest way would be to send it to the server side Node.js, then to Python from there. I can think of a few options:

1. The child_process/spawn option. I had a bit of code to try and do this, but it wasn't working. I don't really understand the concept, and the tutorials out there are not very helpful. Their sample code is riddled with errors and they don't explain what's going on. If you think this is the answer, could you please give some sample code and explain how it works? I can then adapt it to my situation.
2. The HTTP through Flask approach. I tried this also, and I got GET requests to work, but not POST requests. Could someone explain how to implement GET and POST requests between Python/Flask and Node.js? I'm using Heroku, if that makes a difference. By the way, the Python program is not a Flask script yet, but I'm willing to make it into one if this ends up being the best way.
3. The socket module in Python and Node.js. My program uses socket and io in Node.js and JavaScript to run server-side functions with the client-side code. Can I use the Python socket module to define server-side functions that I can call from my client-side JS? Something like `socket.emit("socket_function_name", argument);`

Would any of these work for what I am trying to accomplish? If so, how would it work in my situation? The reason why I'm asking such a specific question is because nobody has given me a straight answer as of yet.

Comment: If you have two web apps, the right way to communicate between them is via HTTP, which you describe as "the Flask approach" for some reason. You will need to show what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I tried all three of those options. I'm not new at Node.js or Python, I'm new at combining them. I'm not sure there is a "right" way, I'm just asking what my options are. Also, to send something through HTTP, you use Flask, correct? If you know another way, please tell me, that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Er, no..? Are you already using Flask for the Python side of your app?

Comment: No I'm not. But I'm willing to if that's the best way to communicate between Python and Node.js. Maybe leave an answer with some sample code so you have more space to describe the "right" way.

Comment: But the problem is you haven't explained what your Python side actually is. If it is not already a Flask app, then what is it? What does it do?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll add it to the question. This piece of it does a lot of stuff. Some scientific computation, some SQL database handling, even some language processing. Right now I'm focusing on the SQL handling part, its a login database. So JavaScript sends Python the username and password, Python replies with a error message or a success message.